# ambiguous symbols

Tags: compiler-construction, visual-c++, linker, managed-c++

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\objidl.h(5934) : error C2872: 'IDataObject' : ambiguous symbol
1>        could be 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\objidl.h(251) : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject IDataObject'
1>        or       'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject
```

can anyone help with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project imports System.Windows.Forms from two places, from the SDK and from the deployed .Net framework. Fix your sources and/or include paths to include it only once, prefferably the one from the SDK.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to fix this? I started experiencing this after removing a certain file/class from the project, and I don't see where I am including both the SDK and the .Net framework.